# Flask cookies.get returning none on React fetch request even with 'credentials: "include"'

Tags: reactjs, flask, cookies

I've trying to make a fetch request from my React app to my backend Flask server that will user a token id saved in cookies.
I previously set the cookie and it shows in browser but when I try to make the request it shows that comes back with error saying it returned none

#### Front-end

```
fetch(url, {
  credentials: 'include'
}).then((response) => ...
```

#### Back-end

```
@app.route('/cookie', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def api_get_cookie():
    print(request.cookies) // print empty dictionary
    return request.cookies.get('token')
```

Comment: Same. I have this problem. Have you found the problem?